# Constexpr for creating objects

Tags: c++, constexpr

I'm trying to figure out if there is a performance gain of creating objects with `constexpr` instead of normally.

Here is the code snippet for `constexpr`.

```
class Rect
{
    const int a;
    const float b;
public:
    constexpr Rect(const int a,const float b)
    : a(a),b(b){}
};

int main()
{
     constexpr Rect rect = Rect(1,2.0f);
}
```

And without `constexpr`.

```
class Rect
{
    int a;
    float b;
public:
    Rect(int a, float b)
    : a(a),b(b){}
};

int main()
{
    Rect rect = Rect(1,2.0f);
}
```

I was expecting there will be a lot less code for `constexpr` since the memory should be initialized at compile-time.

Am I using `constexpr` properly? And if that is not true, can you use `constexpr` to create the objects at compile-time and then use them without any runtime overhead?

Thanks!

Comment: _"The constexpr specifier declares that it is __possible__ to evaluate the value of the function or variable at compile time"_ source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr . Not that it is required to be evaluate at compile time.  Try changing `Rect rect = Rect(1,2.0f);` to `constexpr Rect rect{1,2.0f};`

Comment: Why the downvote? This is well written and *not* obvious (at least, not to me).

Comment: I mean, there's not going to be a difference when you turn optimization on because you don't do anything with `rect`, so [it will get removed](https://godbolt.org/g/hQxTnU) whether or not you use `constexpr`. You can't get more efficient than no code!

Comment: When compiling without optimizations, [there is a substantial difference](https://godbolt.org/g/tB7kRG) in the generated code. So I'm going to call this question flawed because you're likely compiling with optimizations enabled and comparing output where all of your code is removed as dead anyway. If you want us to look further into this, please provide your compiler version and options (or just a link to your compiler explorer sample).

Comment: @cdhowie yes the code from the compiler is not exactly the same with no optimizations but I was expecting there would be lot less code for `constexpr` only some `mov` instructions since the compiler only need to fill the data for the object.

Comment: @PetarVelev cdhowie's point was that the code is removed completely because it doesn't do anything, so obviously `constexpr` doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @interjay i know that it will generate the same instructions with optimizations cause there is nothing happening in `main()` but i expected a drastic difference between the both cases and what I'm seeing some lines for the constructor. Regardless. Thanks for the comments they helped me figure out some of the things that I'm asking.

Comment: @PetarVelev But cdhowie's link shows a substantial difference between the two in an unoptimized build.

Comment: @interjay Whoah yeah thats a different story. In my example I'm using `x86-64 gcc 7.1` without any compiler options and the things look different.
cdhowie's results are the things that I was expecting to see.
Should I remove the question since this is because of the compiler?

Comment: It turned out that I had some headers included  from previous example. Most of the code generated came from them. 
Now it looks like cdhowie's example.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I had some headers included which were responsible for the similarity of the code.

The answer is that there is a big difference between both cases.

> When compiling without optimizations, [there is a substantial difference](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:%27class+Rect%0A%7B%0A++++int+a%3B%0A++++float+b%3B%0Apublic:%0A++++constexpr+Rect(int+a,+float+b)%0A++++:+a(a),b(b)%7B%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++constexpr+Rect+rect+%3D+Rect(1,2.0f)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:100,l:%274%27,m:51.694915254237294,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:2,source:%27class+Rect%0A%7B%0A++++int+a%3B%0A++++float+b%3B%0Apublic:%0A++++Rect(int+a,+float+b)%0A++++:+a(a),b(b)%7B%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++Rect+rect+%3D+Rect(1,2.0f)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%232%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:100,l:%274%27,m:48.30508474576271,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:34.75791334251309,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g63,filters:(b:%270%27,commentOnly:%270%27,directives:%270%27,intel:%270%27),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B11+-O0%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+6.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:28.154966278965773,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g63,filters:(b:%270%27,commentOnly:%270%27,directives:%270%27,intel:%270%27),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B11+-O0%27,source:2),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+6.3+(Editor+%232,+Compiler+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:37.08712037852113,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) in the generated code...
>                                                                     -cdhowie